# Handle validation jquery after paste event in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I wrote this code :

```
$("input").on("paste", async function () {
        await sleep(100);
    });
// Copy paste delay
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

On desktop, it works but on mobile, paste doesn’t work (I mean validation doesn’t work when I paste in input). How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

$(this).bind('paste',async function () {
await sleep(100)
const valid = $(this).valid();

```
            if ($(this).attr('websitePassword') !== undefined) {
                validatePassword($(this));
                valid ? $('.invalid-feedback--list').hide() : $('.invalid-feedback--list').show();
            }

            changeValidationDesign($(this));
          });
```

Comment: Perfect, my problem solved with your solution,Thanks